# how to get employee count by Hour and Date using pySpark / python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have employee id, their clock in, and clock out timings by day. I want to calculate number of employee present in office by hour by Date.

Example Data

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'emp_id': ['Employee 1', 'Employee 2', 'Employee 3', 'Employee 4', 'Employee 5'],
    'Clockin': ['12/5/2021 0:08','8/7/2021 0:04','3/30/2021 1:24','12/23/2021 22:45', '12/23/2021 23:29'],
    'Clockout': ['12/5/2021 3:28','8/7/2021 0:34','3/30/2021 4:37','12/24/2021 0:42', '12/24/2021 1:42']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

Example of output

```
import pandas as pd
data2 = {'Date': ['12/5/2021', '8/7/2021', '3/30/2021','3/30/2021','3/30/2021','3/30/2021', '12/23/2021','12/23/2021','12/24/2021','12/24/2021'],
    'Hour': ['01:00','01:00','02:00','03:00','04:00','05:00', '22:00','23:00', '01:00','02:00'],
    'emp_count': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2, 2,1]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

Comment: Does an employee needs to be present for the full hour to be considered "present" for that hour? Or any presence will do? For example, is employee present during the hour of `12/5/2021 00:00`?

Comment: employee need not to be present for the full hour. please consider '01:00' as "00:00  to 01:00", and 02:00 as "01:00 to 02:00".

Comment: The expected result doesn't reflect the "full hour" rule. Employee 1 starts at 00:08, so they can't be present for the hour ending at 01:00. They must start on or before 00:00 to be counted.

Comment: expected result:

Comment: expected result:  If an employee start at 00:08 and exit at 02:15 then he well be counted in '01:00', '02:00' and '03:00' hour.

Comment: So if the employee works even 1 minute in the hour, they are counted as present for that hour?

Comment: yes!, this is what I want.

Comment: thank you @code-different, got my output,  The only change required is  `inclusive="both"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
# Round clock in DOWN to the nearest PRECEDING hour
clock_in = pd.to_datetime(df1["Clockin"]).dt.floor("H")
# Round clock out UP to the nearest SUCCEEDING hour
clock_out = pd.to_datetime(df1["Clockout"]).dt.ceil("H")

# Generate time series at hourly frequency between adjusted clock in and clock
# out time
hours = pd.Series(
    [
        pd.date_range(in_, out_, freq="H", inclusive="right")
        for in_, out_ in zip(clock_in, clock_out)
    ]
).explode()

# Final result
hours.groupby(hours).count()
```

Result:

```
2021-03-30 02:00:00    1
2021-03-30 03:00:00    1
2021-03-30 04:00:00    1
2021-03-30 05:00:00    1
2021-08-07 01:00:00    1
2021-12-05 01:00:00    1
2021-12-05 02:00:00    1
2021-12-05 03:00:00    1
2021-12-05 04:00:00    1
2021-12-23 23:00:00    1
2021-12-24 00:00:00    2
2021-12-24 01:00:00    2
2021-12-24 02:00:00    1
dtype: int64
```

It's slightly different from your expected output but consistent with your business rules.